Deployed node.js app to GKE with Deployment produsing errors errorInfoMetadata: { permission: 'logging.logEntries.create' }"
GKE node-pool created with custom service account and enabled roles/logging.writer permissions.
But kubernetes deployment logs show an error:
note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient',
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
statusDetails: [
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
ErrorInfo {
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
metadata: { permission: 'logging.logEntries.create' },
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
reason: 'IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED',
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
domain: 'iam.googleapis.com'
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
}
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
],
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
reason: 'IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED',
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
domain: 'iam.googleapis.com',
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
errorInfoMetadata: { permission: 'logging.logEntries.create' }
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
}
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC
2024-09-19 11:37:02.361 UTC

Node.js v18.20.4
Where to look more?
Tried on
GKE versions tried: 1.29.7-gke.1104000 and latest
GKE node-pools were also created with default service accounts - all the same.

Hi, please see formatting help

The default Compute Engine service account (by default) includes roles/editor which includes logging.logEntries.create and you state (without evidence) that a Service Account bound to the permission was also used. The evidence contracts your statements. Please update your question so that it represents a minimal repro, demonstrating your assertions and the resultant output.
